# Find the local and global extrema of a Euclidean metric over an one-sheeted hyperboloid.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $F: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined as $F(x):= -x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2 \forall x \in \mathbb{R^3}$ and $ A=F^{-1}([1;2])$.
>
> Find all the local and global Maxima and Minima of $f:=d( \cdot, 0)$ of $A$ where $d$ is the Euclidean metric, meaning $f(x):= \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R^3}.$
>
> Tip: Try sketching the set $A$. It can make sense instead of $f$, to extremalize a different function. For finding the extreme points it can make sense to set one coordinate as $0$ and for the other coordinates to use hyperbolic functions $(\sinh,\cosh)$ - but you can do it a different way as well.

- This was one of the exam problems I was given in analysis and boy did I fail big time. So I tried approaching this problem in a number of ways, I tried setting $x_2=0$ and using the parameterization $(\sinh t,0, \cosh t)$. But no matter how I look at it, sketching this looks like a one-sheeted hyperboloid and how does one find maxima and minima on quadric surfaces, the smallest distance I could potentially see is the small radius on the smallest ellipse, I wouldn't know how to present that mathematically though. Please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: $x=(\sinh t,0,\cosh t)\in A$ shows that $f$ has no (global) maximum on $A$, since $\sinh^2t+\cosh^2t=\cosh2t\to\infty$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: By $F^{-1}([1;2])$ you mean the set of all $x$ such that $1\leq F(x)\leq2$, right?

Comment: That's what i thought at first, but apparently it's the wrong answer. $F^{-1}([1;2)]$ means all the values for $x \in \mathbb{R^3}$ for which the solutions are 1 and 2. for example $-x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1$ and $-x_1^2+2x_2^2+x_3^2=2$. Maybe one shouldn't approach the problem with sinh and cosh and try the ellipses that grow bigger and bigger as they go further from the center. But I'm out of ideas at is point.